# How can I use hibernate with MS Access?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, ms-access, orm

I want to use hibernate with MS Access. Which dialect should I use and can you give me a sample hibernate configuration file with MS Access?

Comment: If you don't mind. Why? Would it not be possible to swicth to another DB like SQLite?

Comment: While I think that looking for something else is a good suggestion, SQLite might not be the "best" alternative as it's not well supported by Hibernate (even if things like this http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/ do exist).

Comment: It sounds like @VincentRamdhanie has never worked in a corporate environment :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For MS Access, you'll need the dialect from [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html). You'll need to use the [hibernate support package](http://www.hxtt.com/test/hibernate.zip) provided by HXTT. There is also a [sample project](http://www.hxtt.com/test/HibernateTest.zip) that you can check for a fully working example.

Below, a sample minimal configuration:

```
# Hxtt Access dialect sample
hibernate.dialect=com.hxtt.support.hibernate.HxttAccessDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.hxtt.sql.access.AccessDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:access:///c:/yourAccessDirectory
```

PS: If MS Access is not a written in stone requirement, maybe you should consider using something else like... well, anything.

Comment: +1 for the PS. If I could you would get another +1 for actually answering the question too.

Comment: -1 for the PS without any explanation of why -- there are plenty of applications that you might be using Hibernate for without it being inappropriate to use a file-server data store like Jet/ACE.

Comment: @David Isn't non official support from Hibernate enough for you? To me, it is, I don't want to rely on a third party dialect provider.

Comment: -1 @Pascal Thivent : A paying solution is not a solution, because if you think like that, you just need to pay 10,000 $ to a company to solve all of your problems. A lot of persons search a free solution for this problem and we continue to search... ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618065/using-hibernate-with-ms-access-2007-database-free-jdbc-driver )

Answer (score 15):

**Actual solution here!**

After spending 1 day trying out different solutions ODBC, HXTT, etc. I found this beauty :) http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html.

It couldn't be any simpler: just add the jars from the site to your project libs and.

**META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="traderMandate">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/MY.accdb;" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Spring config:**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="traderMandate"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And you're good to go. ;)

Comment: Is org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect really the correct dialect while using this approach?

Comment: It is. The given example is a copy paste from my working solution. I assume the driver basically acts like an adapter and _makes_ the accdb file _SQLServerDialect-compatible_.

Comment: @GergelyKovács hi i  know the question is pretty old but did your programm work well all the way ? i tried it but with some querries it has SqlSyntaxErrorException

Answer (score 1):

You can use an other strategy and a free strategy to resolve this problem (HXTT is not free) :

http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/06/how-to-use-ms-access-with-hibernate.html

Personaly I got an exception when I try to reverse engineering the ms database (org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error while reading primary key meta data), yet it works for many people.

Comment: " I don't know where it works perfectly or not, but I did an experiment using SQLServerDialect to connect msaccess database file".  Anyone using a driver to connect to a database that has not been certified by Hibernate to work properly with their s/w is taking a risk.  Certification means doing more than connecting and running a single SELECT query.  Please cite who "many people" are.  I have no statistics to support this assertion.

Answer (score 1):

As a late note (commenting is not available for me): UCanAccess surely works, although I don't (yet) have experience with writing data. Anyways, regarding the dialect to use, I run with

```
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
```

because UCanAccess use HSQLDB, and I suppose that dialect is the best match. There isn't any sql actually hitting ms-access in the picture here, jackcess reads and writes directly to the access mdb-file, there is no microsoft code interpreting any sql anywhere, as far as I can understand, and therefore using SQLServerDialect will only confuse HSQLDB code trying to understand it.

Comment: While it is true that the UCanAccess JDBC driver uses HSQLDB as its backing database, UCanAccess also pre-processes SQL statements to try and support the Access SQL dialect as much as possible. The UCanAccess team hopes to be able to provide a "UCanAccessDialect" for Hibernate users, but that is one of many things currently on the to-do list.

Comment: That would just be for compability with existing sql from existing Access databases, right? Still the sql would be translated to jackcess-calls in the end, I guess?

Comment: That's right. The intention would be to support the Access SQL syntax as much as possible. Ultimately, UCanAccess would still be using the Jackcess API to actually update the database file.

Answer (score 0):

@Firstthumb. Sorry, this is not really an answer but just expressing a comment. I was in the same boat - considering using MS Access to develop a local tipping competition for the Football World Cup 2010. I could access MS Access directly using the Oledb but as a training exercise to reskill a bunch of Java developers moving to .NET, I wanted to show the usage of nHibernate as the DAO layer.

After investigating the non-availability of a robust and supported dialect from JBoss/Hibernate team and other considerations, I decided to forego the exercise on using MSAccess. I downloaded the free SQL Express 2008 instead.

For those who still want to use MSAccess in .NET, please see [this link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate))