# Dialect used when connecting to MS Access database using Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, ms-access, grails, datasource

I am to connect to MS Access database in my application that uses grails.

I am in the process of configuring my Datasource.groovy, but am not sure of the dialect to be used.
Any help?

EDIT: Thoughts on this question???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails uses Hibernate under the hood, and it seems you need some efforts to make Hibernate to work with Access. Unfortunately, Access is not supported officially by Hibernate. So I recommend changing into an officially supported database(MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL...)

But if you insist using Access, you can take the Hibernate dialect for Access from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access). It will take some effort to make things work, and remember, this stuff maynot be maintained in the future.

Comment: @ Hoang : No choice in data base. Have to use Access. I suppose hxtt license is not free...isn it? In that case What would you suggest...A couple of sites suggested usage of net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MSAccessDialect. Thoughts on this?? Not sure which jar or package is to be used for this though? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the xml syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=d:/temp/Database9.accdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>          
        <mapping resource="com/prj/domain/prj.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```