# Can I use an MS Access JDBC driver in Spring Roo?

Tags: java, ms-access, jpa, jdbc, spring-roo

I need to write a RESTful API (and later a web front end) that uses a legacy MS Access DB on the backend.

I'm fairly familiar with Java and have worked on projects using Spring in the past.  I've recently played around a bit with Spring Roo and really like what I see so far, so I was hoping to use it if possible.  I've also used [a nifty JDBC driver for Access](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) before.  So I think I have most of the pieces I need.

My question is: can I use that Access JDBC driver with Roo?  I'm not very familiar with JPA, so I'm not sure if having a JDBC driver is sufficient or if I'd also need a custom JPA layer.  If this is possible, how would I do it?  If not, do you have alternative suggestions?  Would it be worth it to use Roo or should I go another route?

Thanks very much for your help!

Tom

Comment: A jdbc driver should be enough, so I guess it will work. Why don't you try it?

Comment: If it has JDBC support it will work.  fI assume you know that MS Access is not really meant for this sort of thing and will not be able to scale to handle any serious volume or load.

Comment: @BrianC: Yes, I'm aware of that, but thanks for asking!  My goal is to replace a Windows-only front-end with a web/mobile front-end for a software program that uses Access under the hood.  It'd still be used only be one or two users at once and the databases don't get too large.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure.

I think the main problem here is the ORM support for MS Access.

I found [a description to how to configure a Hibernate with ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access). You must configure the `database.properties` and `persistence.xml` files to try it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes but, by default, MSAccess isn't supported in Spring Roo.

So, first setup your persistence layer using any of the supported databases, for example POSTGRES:

```
roo> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database POSTGRES
```

Then customize database properties using `database properties set` command. To see current database connection settings use `database properties list`:

```
roo> database properties list
# expected output
database.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
database.password = 
database.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
database.username =
```