# Grails connection to Ms Access

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have read a lot of old posts saying that Grails can't connect to Access unless you do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access)  and after reading the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-dialects) of hibernate I couldn't find Ms. Access, is there a "clean and easy" way to connect to Ms. Access from Grails?

PS: I have to make the connection to Access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linked response, it seems that you need to download the [HXTT hibernate support](http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html). Put the jar in your lib folder or install in your m2 local repository and declare it in your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

After, you can configure hibernate in the `DataSource.groovy`:

```
hibernate {
  dialect = com.hxtt.support.hibernate.HxttAccessDialect
  connection.driverClass = com.hxtt.sql.access.AccessDriver
}
```

And in your development block put the url like the example in the HXTT site.