# Cannot connect to database using hibernate with Microsoft Access

Tags: java, hibernate, ms-access-2007, hibernate-mapping

I got this exception:

```
1266 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Running hbm2ddl schema export
1266 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - exporting generated schema to database
1266 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - schema export unsuccessful
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at com.vaannila.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at com.vaannila.student.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at com.vaannila.student.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Please help me out from this issue. Here is my configuration file:

```
 <hibernate-configuration> 
 <session-factory> 
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
 <property name="connection.password"></property> 
 <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property> 
 <property name="hibernate.conn.url">jdbc:odbc:demo</property>
```

Comment: Can you show us where you are setting up hibernate and passing it aconfiguration string?

Comment: my hibernate-configuration file is attached below.
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.conn.url">jdbc:odbc:demo</property>

Comment: have you tried to connect to an other db, e.g. hsqldb or h2?

Answer (score 0):

Check your hibernate property names.

> hibernate.conn.url

should be:

> hibernate.connection.url

Your

> connection.passsword

should be

> hibernate.connection.password

The rest look good, though recheck the docs. I see you have an empty password field and username properties.  Does your odbc connection require a name and passsword?

Fixing the connection string will at least give you a new type of error if you are missing other information like login credentials.

These xml configs are terribly fussy!

Comment: above error is resolved but now i am getting below exception1665 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: insert into ADDRESS (ADDRESS_STREET, ADDRESS_CITY, ADDRESS_STATE, ADDRESS_ZIPCODE) values (?, ?, ?, ?) select scope_identity()
1824 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -3516, SQLState: 37000
1824 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter -

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.vaannila.student.Address]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)

Comment: at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2327)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2834)
 at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)

Comment: at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)

Comment: at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
 at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)

Comment: Looks like you're going to need to get an access dialect.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access. Or some other :).  You may have more luck if you import the access data into sql server express or developers edition (it's been so long since I've done MS stuff)