# Getting the SQLGrammarException when trying to insert a record in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, ms-access-2013

I am getting the following exception - 
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [Employee]
Here are the details:
**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:/Hibernate.accdb</property>
            <property name="connection.username"></property>
            <property name="connection.password"></property>
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-conf
```

**Employee.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
   private int id;
   private String firstName; 
   private String lastName;   
   private int salary;  

   public Employee() {}
   public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
      this.firstName = fname;
      this.lastName = lname;
      this.salary = salary;
   }
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

**ManageEmployee.java**

```
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator; 

import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();

      /* Add few employee records in database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali", 1000);
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das", 5000);
      Integer empID3 = ME.addEmployee("John", "Paul", 10000);
}
 public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, int salary){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return employeeID;
   }

}
```

Here is the full exception:

> Output in console:
>   Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (first_name, last_name, salary) values (?, ?, ?) select scope_identity()
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [Employee]
>   Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (first_name, last_name, salary) values (?, ?, ?) select scope_identity()
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2327)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2834)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
>       at ManageEmployee.addEmployee(ManageEmployee.java:47)
>       at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:23)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$InsertSelectDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:138)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
>       ... 17 more
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [Employee]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2327)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2834)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
>       at ManageEmployee.addEmployee(ManageEmployee.java:47)
>       at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:24)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$InsertSelectDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:138)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
>       ... 17 more
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [Employee]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2327)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2834)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
>       at ManageEmployee.addEmployee(ManageEmployee.java:47)
>       at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:25)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$InsertSelectDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:138)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
>       ... 17 more
>   Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (first_name, last_name, salary) values (?, ?, ?) select scope_identity()

Please help to resolve the exceptions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please go over the tutorial for submitting questions. Your question does not comply with the common standard, please revise it.

Comment: Please clarify and structure your question

Comment: thank u for your edit @kinshuk4.

Answer (score 0):

The MS Access dialect does not exists in the Hibernate library. This causes that Hibernate is not capable to detect the **identity** column and act as required for MS Access.

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [Employee] Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (first_name, last_name, salary) values (?, ?, ?) **select scope_identity()**

**select scope_identity()** is a [TRANSACT-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) instance not supported by MS Access.

You could do one of this options:

- Don't use autogenerated id columns or no SQL standard fields.
- Use a supported hibernate database insted of MS Access [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-dialects).
- Create your own hibernate dialect to support MS Access or use a [thirdparty one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access) to provide the special characteristics of MS Access.

Related to [How can I use hibernate with MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access)