# Hibernate - org.hibernate.MappingException when using net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, ucanaccess

I am trying to query an access db in java 8 and i use maven. I am using `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver` for my connection and below is my **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property     
    name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> 
    net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\db\\QIDB-Access\\db.mdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">     </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">     </property>
<mapping resource="IndikatorProcessor.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My class with annotations looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Indikator")
public class IndikatorProcessor {

@Id
@Column(name = "QI_ID")
private int qiId;

public int getQiId() {
    return qiId;
}

public void setQiId(int qiId) {
    this.qiId = qiId;
}

}
```

In another class i create the session and write a simple query:

```
  ....
  public void listQIIndikator() {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<?> indikators = session.createQuery("From IndikatorProcessor").list();
        for (Iterator<?> iterator = indikators.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            IndikatorProcessor indiaktor = (IndikatorProcessor) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Indikator ID = " + indiaktor.getQiId());
        }
        tx.commit();
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: IndikatorProcessor is not mapped
```

I am not sure what causes the error since it is mapped! Is it the query or using the ucanaccess driver for the connection?

Now i added a `IndikatorProcessor.hbm.xml` as folow and changed the hibernate file to use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="IndikatorProcessor" table="Indikator">
  <meta attribute="class-description">
     This class contains the Indikator detail. 
  </meta>

    <id name="qiId" type="int" column="QI_ID"> <!--  <generator    class="native"/> -->  </id>

 <!--  <property name="qiId" column="QI_ID" type="int"/> -->
  <property name="fkQig" column= "FK_QIG"></property>
```

Now i get these errors:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class IndikatorProcessor not found while looking for property: fkQig
```

and

```
Caused by:  org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable  to load class [IndikatorProcessor]
```

Comment: You are using the wrong dialect..

Comment: Is there a particular dialect for access?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access i found SQLServerDialect but it dose not work either

Comment: You can use dialect from [link]HXTT(http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html). But if at all possible, try using some other database...

Comment: Did u test a native query working? Are you sure annotations in IndikatorProcessor.java are processed since I didn't see <mapping> property in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Do i need a mapping property, when i use annotaion? I thought mapping is to refer the mappin xml. But i do not have mapping XML. Just annotations

Comment: Where is your mappings for annotated class (Entity)? Sadly, Hibernate does not Scan for annotated classes at startup and so you have to configure Hibernate manually, either through an XML configuration file or Pro-grammatically, so that it knows about your annotated classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception says your `IndikatorProcessor` is not mapped in **SessionFactory**, so do a mapping as follows:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\db\\QIDB-Access\\db.mdb</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username"> </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password"> </property>
   <mapping class="your.package.IndikatorProcessor"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

hibernate could not find the class without giving the package name. I added the package name in `IndikatorProcessor.hbm.xml` and it worked.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="model.IndikatorProcessor" table="Indikator">
  <meta attribute="class-description">
     This class contains the Indikator detail. 
    </meta>
  <id name="qiId" type="int" column="QI_ID">  </id>

  <property name="fkQig" type ="int" column= "FK_QIG"></property>
```