# Switching from Ms Access database with Hibernate supported Database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Note : I have read and tried this : [How can I use hibernate with MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749464/how-can-i-use-hibernate-with-ms-access)

i tried to make my Hibernate app works with Ms Access ( yeah i know, its bad) with ucanaccess but it didnt work quite properly with paging and such. So i figured that i need to let access go and choose another database type. But the system in which this app is deployed has this requirement:

You counldnt install any programm on this, only copying files.

Thus using a mysql database is impossible (at least for me) because i will need to install mysqlserver on it , what i can't. What i need is a type of database which you only needs to convert from Ms Access to it and save it somewhere you want.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not yet have enough points to comment - so I'll leave this as an answer (it kinda, sorta is).  Sounds to me like a job for [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).  Converting your data is up to you though...